# iterating through 2 lists containing class instances

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have 2 lists, one static variable and a class instance that takes 4 attributes.

The lists contain class instances that have variables of their own.

The static variable is to be used in all class instances.

The class instance takes 2 variables from each class instance from list_a, one variable from list_b, and the last slot is for the static variable.

```
static_variable = 1
list_a = [class_instance]  
list_b = [class_instance]
class_instance(data1_from_list_a, data2_from_list_a, data6_from_list_b, static_variable) #<--- this class instance takes 4 attributes.
```

The instances inside those 2 lists are instances from these 2 classes:

```
class FOO:
    def__init__(self, data1, data2, data3) #<---- Foo instances inside list_a

class BAR:
    def __init__(self, data4, data5, data6) #<---- Bar instances inside list_b
```

I want to iterate those 2 list simultaneously and put the first 2 variables from list_a in to the first 2 slots of my class_instance, the third variable is from list_B and the 4th variable is the static variable.

How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to iterate over? Do you want to generate many such classes?

Comment: yes. i want to generate as many class instances as there are class instances in the list. in the example there are 3 class instances in each of these 2 lists.

Comment: Could you provide a slightly less abstract example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your real question is about how to iterate over the two lists in parallel. Unlike other languages where the answer is generally to iterate on an index, in Python you can use the `zip` function to iterate multiple lists at once. Here's a simple example, using a list comprehension to build a sequence of new instances using data from the instances in your two existing lists:

```
result = [MyClass(a.data1, a.data2, b.data6, static_var) for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

The `zip` call returns an iterator that yields 2-tuples which get unpacked into the variables `a` and `b`. Those references to the instances can then have their attributes accessed to get at the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a class like

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, b1, s):
        ...
```

and you want to create instances of `Foo` using elements from `list_a` to fill `a1` and `a2`, elements from `b` to fill `b` and use `static_variable` to fill `s`. Try this:

```
a_iter = iter(list_a)
instances = [ Foo(next(a_iter), next(a_iter), b, s) for b in list_b ]
```

I'm also assuming that `len(list_a) == 2*len(list_b)`, so that the iterator for `list_a` doesn't run out before the iterator for `list_b` does.

Comment: Yes those 2 lists have always the same number of instances. I get the error "TypeError: list object is not an iterator". Also the class instances inside those lists contain many attributes and i want specific ones.

Comment: Oops, forgot to actually call `iter` to set the value of `a_iter`. You'll need to provide more detail about what is actually *in* the lists.

Comment: I edited my post above you can see the structure of the classes that are inside those lists. I hope you can understand better now.

Comment: So `list_a` contains instances of `Foo`, and `list_b` contains instances of `Bar`. It's still not clear to me what `class_instance` refers to, if not what I outline in the answer. You are going to have to post some actual, executable code that accomplishes your end goal, if not as efficiently as you would like.